# Como hacer un menu vertical en rails?

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

La verdad tengo un problema que pienso es de noob.

Resulta que estoy creando un panel para mis usuarios y quiero crear un menu vertical, el problema es que quiero que se cargue en una parte de la página.  dejo una imagen para que me entiendan. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quizás existe alguna gema, pero antes de aventurarme preferí preguntar.

Que estén bien .

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo dos opciones, con rails haces el funcionamiento.

y Bootstrap lo demás.

[Bootstrap + css](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/GWzw5/2/)

[Jasny Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/tV3Mf/3/)

En tu archivo layout dentro de las etiquetas head añade lo siguiente:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Y ya con eso tendrás el bootstrap para menús verticales listo para usar en cualquier apartado, solo tienes que crear la estructura como se muestra en los jsfiddles, con esas clases en donde quieras tener tu menú.

Comment: Lo recomendable es que coloques aquí mismo la solución y no _links_ hacia otros lados :s

Comment: Son links a jsfiddle para que vea el codigo y funcionamiento, saludos.
 ; )

Comment: El problema que tengo es como hago el funcionamiento en rails. 
Saludos.

Comment: @MiguelAbdonHollstein he editado la respuesta y añadido algo mas por favor revisalo, en realidad no es complicado realizar este añadido.

Mira la documentacion aqui: [enlace]http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap [enlace]